# Update Excel data using form

Tags: excel, vb.net, forms

My challenge is to update a big excel data through Form, user will not directly update into sheet, instead he will update into a Form which will update the backend sheet. As this is a huge excel creating Userform with so many field is critical, is there any other option like Form wizard in Access.

Please suggest.

Regards,

Comment: Excel has data forms: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Simplify-data-entry-with-a-data-form-00bfc75e-f675-46ad-8703-291fc03e4d77 for Mac, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-edit-find-and-delete-rows-by-using-a-data-form-17bca0a4-3ba5-444a-983c-a8ce70609374 for PC. Perhaps it could be a quick solution instead dealing with VBA.

Comment: Why dont you use multiple user forms with all data fields in it. user will input values and click next, and 2nd form will appear and so on.

Comment: There are no easy way to do this. Use the visual basic feature of excel under "developer" tab. It should create a default form which you can add or update data from a form to spreadsheet. Just run it using a macro command upon opening the excel file, but it requires coding as well. Try searching for VBA coding articles.